# How do you remove duplicate values then display unique values?

Tags: java, arrays, count, duplicates, output

```
public class nrlSports {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] direction = {"north", "north", "east", "south", "south", "south", "north", "north"};

        for(int i=0; i<direction.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < direction.length; j++)
                if(direction[i].equals(direction[j])) {
                    count++;
                }
            System.out.println(direction[i] + " (" + count + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:
north (4)
north (4)
east (1)
south (3)
south (3)
south (3)
north (4)
north (4)

How do I remove these duplicate values so the output should look like this:
north (4)
east (1)
south (3)

Comment: Add all the elements of the array to a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Comment: Will the array be sorted always ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this approach

```
String[] direction = { "north", "north", "east", "south", "south",
        "south", "north", "north" };

Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();//to preserve order or elements
for (String key : direction) {
    if (map.containsKey(key))
        map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
    else
        map.put(key, 1);
}
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "(" + entry.getValue() + ")"+
                String.format("%"+entry.getValue()+"s", "").replace(' ', '*'));
```

output

```
north(4)****
east(1)*
south(3)***
```

Comment: yes that's perfect. how do you add star *, for example
north(4): ****
east(1): *
south(3): ***

Comment: excellent thanks. one thing i don't understand is '\u0000'. what does that do?

Comment: @Shuvo0o I changed code and not using `\u0000` anymore. By default empty char array is filled with `\u0000` which is first unicode character, so entire string also contains only them. Now I am using `String.format("%"+entry.getValue()+"s", "")`. If you use it like `String.format("%5s", "")` it will produce String containing exactly 5 spaces `"     "`. Later I replace every space with `*`.

Answer (score 1):

This can help :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] direction = {"north", "north", "east", "south", 
                          "south", "south", "north", "north"};
    Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for(int i=0; i<direction.length; i++) {
        String key = direction[i];
        if(!countMap.containsKey(key)){
            countMap.put(key, 1);
        }
        else 
        {
            countMap.put(key, countMap.get(key)+1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(countMap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thought the solution is not optimized one but will work (confirmed by running it :) )

```
        String[] direction = {"north", "north", "east", "south", "south", "south", "north", "north"};
    HashMap<String,Integer> myHash = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


    for(int i=0; i<direction.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < direction.length ; j++)
            if(direction[i].equals(direction[j])) {
                count++;
                myHash.put(direction[i], new Integer(count));                    
            }
    }

       Iterator T = (Iterator) myHash.entrySet().iterator();
       while( T.hasNext() ) 
       {
            Map.Entry newEntery = (Map.Entry) T.next();                
            System.out.print(newEntery.getKey() +"("+ newEntery.getValue()+")");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a set . Add all of them to a set and you will get unique values.

EDIT:
I missed count part. Adding it now

```
String[] direction = {"north", "north", "east", "south", 
                          "south", "south", "north", "north"};

    Map<String,int> m = new HashMap<String,int>();

 for(String str:direction){
    if(m.contains(str))
       m.put(key,m.get(str)+1);
    else
       m.put(key,1);
}


//key is all values you want to add and count in no. of times values is repeated.
```

So if you want all the unique values, you can iterate over keyset and get corresponding count from Map.

Answer (score 0):

My possible simple way is

```
Set<String> directionS= new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(direction));
```

and then play with  `directionS`